# Ubuntu Booting failed to parse WDG method

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I just installed ubuntu V. 22.04. Everything works fine except when i boot it up i get the following message "failed to parse WDG method" everything boots up correctly afterwards.

So should i be concerned for such a message. note that i use a dell inspiron 5491 2n1 and it used RAID. however i switched to ahci because ubuntu does not support RAID now both windows and ubuntu can dual boot. could any of this be correlated with this message ?[image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63GEx.png)